# Which one, "big" or "scary lady", does the speaker want to stress in the below sentence?

Tags: word-stress

In the sentence "[there's a big, scary lady...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fbKla4SCx0y9uho9HdDtn6Yl0p7oZNDN/view)", I hear "**scary lady**" was said in a **flat tone**, while "**big**" was said in a **higher tone** but it's said **quickly** so I don't like there's any special emphasis on "big". So I'm not sure which one the speaker want to stress.

Please tell me Do you think **which one is stressed?**.

Comment: [Related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222944/is-there-any-book-just-giving-examples-about-different-sentence-stresses-convey) (from the same OP) about stressed words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the audio file, it doesn't seem like either word is being stressed over the other one.

However, when multiple adjectives are used, there is [an order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order) in which they normally occur. Adjectives based on your own *opinion* tend to come first, followed by descriptions of *size*, and then *physical qualities*.

Based on this, I would say that as the adjective of "scary" seems to have been demoted from a matter of opinion to a matter of fact, it is the person's *size* that is being emphasised. If the size wasn't important, they would have just said "a scary lady", but this is a *big* scary lady.

I will add though, that there is a difference between how British and American English speakers might say "scary lady". It *could* be intended as a compound noun, like "rocking chair". With compound nouns, Americans have a tendency to put emphasis on the first syllable of the first word, whereas British speakers tend to put emphasis on the first syllable of the second word. For example:

> American: *Rob*in Hood.
>   British: Robin *Hood*.

This can lead to the final adjective sound like it is part of the noun, and any additional emphasis may be lost.

Comment: I disagree that the order of adjectives is marked; “scary big lady” sounds as strange to me as “green great dragon”.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Did you follow the link to the Cambridge dictionary that I included? The order of adjectives may be a rule of thumb, but a rule nonetheless, otherwise "Scary big lady" wouldn't sound wrong to you, which it does to me too. "Great green dragon" also sounds weird, but "great" is a comment on *size*, which would place it *after* colour as a physical attribute. "Fantastic green dragon" sounds right, yes?

Comment: I was alluding to an anecdote of Tolkien: “I first tried to write a story when I was about seven. It was about a dragon. I remember nothing about it except a philological fact. My mother said nothing about the dragon, but pointed out that one could not say ‘a green great [huge] dragon’, but had to say ‘a great green dragon’. I wondered why, and still do.”

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be either? Because I think in this sentence they have equal weight.
"a big lady" could be a friendly cook
"a scary lady" could be any of the local stereotypes of what makes a lady scary.

But in this case both *big* and *scary* are needed as adjectives to summon the complete picture of a lady who is *both* big and scary (and might derive some of the scariness from her size)